# Get value preinstall to define the instalation path

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to create an installer where the user selects the program version, and upon choosing the version, the installation path changes. For example:

- if they choose **Revit 2023**, the path is: `C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\Revit\Addins\2023`.
- but if they choose `Revit 2022`, the path is: `C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\Revit\Addins\2022`.

Currently, the script is not working as it installs it in the path `C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\Revit\Addins` without adding the year. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
[Setup]
AppName=AedasHomesAddin
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={code:GetInstallPath}
DefaultGroupName=AedasHomesAddin
OutputDir=Output
OutputBaseFilename=AedasHomesAddinSetup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
DisableDirPage=yes

[Code]
var
  SelectedVersion: String;
  Page: TInputOptionWizardPage;

function GetSelectedVersion(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result := SelectedVersion;
end;

function GetInstallPath(Param: String): String;
begin
  // Build the installation path based on the selected year.
  Result := ExpandConstant('{commonappdata}\Autodesk\Revit\Addins\' + SelectedVersion);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  // Create a custom page for version selection.
  Page := CreateInputOptionPage(wpWelcome, 'Select Revit Version', 'Choose the Revit version to install:', 'Select the version:', True, False);
  Page.Add('Revit 2019');
  Page.Add('Revit 2020');
  Page.Add('Revit 2021');
  Page.Add('Revit 2022');
  Page.Add('Revit 2023');
  Page.Add('Revit 2024');

  // Initialize SelectedVersion to prevent issues
  SelectedVersion := '';
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  // Store the selected version
  if (CurPageID = Page.ID) and (Page.SelectedValueIndex >= 0) then
  begin
    case Page.SelectedValueIndex of
      0: SelectedVersion := '2019';
      1: SelectedVersion := '2020';
      2: SelectedVersion := '2021';
      3: SelectedVersion := '2022';
      4: SelectedVersion := '2023';
      5: SelectedVersion := '2024';
    end;
  end;
end;


[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\jmore\Documentos\Programacion REVIT\C# Jorge\AedasHomesAddin\bin\Debug\AedasHomesAddin.dll"; DestDir: "{code:GetInstallPath}"
Source: "C:\Users\jmore\Documentos\Programacion REVIT\C# Jorge\AedasHomesAddin\bin\Debug\AedasManifest.addin"; DestDir: "{code:GetInstallPath}"
Source: "C:\Users\jmore\Documentos\Programacion REVIT\C# Jorge\AedasHomesAddin\img\AedasHomes.png"; DestDir: "{code:GetInstallPath}"
```

Comment: Thanks Marvin and StayOnTarget, it worked for me. Would it be possible to select multiple versions and have multiple installation paths?.

Comment: Yes, but that is much more complex.